# Are profinite groups of cardinality $|\mathbb{R}|$ determined by their finite quotients?

Tags: gr.group-theory, fundamental-group

**Question: Let $G,H$ be profinite groups of cardinality $|\mathbb{R}|$, with the same finite quotients (here I only consider quotients by normal, *open* subgroups). Then are $G$ and $H$ isomorphic?**

Background: First, note that one needs some sort of cardinality assumption, as otherwise one could take $G=\mathbb{F}_2^I$ and $H=\mathbb{F}_2^J$ where $I$ and $J$ are infinite of distinct cardinality.  Moreover, it is NOT sufficient to just require that $G$ and $H$ have the same cardinality, as one could take $G=\mathbb{F}_2^I\times \mathbb{F}_3^J$ and $H=\mathbb{F}_2^J\times\mathbb{F}_3^I$.

As for motivation, if we take $C$ to be an affine hyperbolic curve over the algebraic closure of a finite field, then it is known which subgroups occur as finite quotients of the etale fundamental group. Given this phrasing, I assume that this is not enough information to ecover the actual etale fundamental group, and so I wanted an explicit counterexample.

**EDIT: Due to the comments, I think a better question is as follows: Rather than assuming $G$ and $H$ have cardinality $\mathbb{R}$, let me assume instead that they have at most countably many homomorphisms to any finite group.**

This avoids (at least) some counterexamples assuming Luzin' hypothesis.

Let me add that the answer is yes if $G$ and $H$ are topologically finitely generated. This is well know, but as its quick I include a proof:

Note that for each positive integer $n$, $G$ has only finitely many homomorphisms to fintie groups of order at most $n$. Let $G(n)$ be the kernel of all of these, and $G_n$ the corresponding finite quotient. Then $G$ is the inverse limit of the $G_n$. To see this note that the natural map $G\to\varprojlim_n G_n$ is clearly injective, and as it is surjective on every quotient it must also be surjective by compactness.

So it is enough to see that $G_n\cong H_n$. But by assumption, $G$ surjects onto $H_n$, and such a surjection must factor through $G_n$, so $G_n$ surjects onto $H_n$. Likewise $H_n$ surjects onto $G_n$ and since these are finite groups they must be isomorphic.

Comment: Does your counterexample still work with $\mathbb{F}_2^\omega\times\mathbb{F}_3^{\omega_1}$ and $\mathbb{F}_2^{\omega_1}\times\mathbb{F}_3^{\omega}$, if we assume Luzin's hypothesis, that is, that $2^\omega=2^{\omega_1}$? This would still be the size of the continuum $|\mathbb{R}|$, even though $\omega$ and $\omega_1$ have different cardinalities. If so, this would show that it is at least consistent with ZFC that the answer is no, since Luzin's hypothesis is known to be relatively consistent with ZFC.

Comment: Huh, that's cool! Ok, so perhaps its best to replace the cardinality hypothesis with what I originally wanted to say: There are only countably many homomorphisms to any given finite group. I think that removes this kind of counterexample.

Comment: @jacob My view is that when one asks a question that is independent of ZFC, then one has asked precisely the right question, as it is right on the boundary of what can be true and what might be false.

Comment: A simpler countexample under Luzin's hypothesis than in my first comment would be: $\mathbb{F}_2^\omega$ versus $\mathbb{F}_2^{\omega_1}$, which both have size continuum.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Thanks, typo fixed! QiaochuYuan: If the groups are topologically finitely generated then the answer to the question is yes, as the group becomes a *canonical* inverse limit of finite subgroups, namely the quotient by the kernels to all finite subgroups of size at most $n$.

Comment: @jacob: I don't understand how that's enough. Two such groups can still fail to be isomorphic if e.g. they admit different numbers of homomorphisms to some finite group.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: You can read off from which finite quotient occur, the NUMBER of such occurences. To see this, suppose you have 2 (non-conjugate) homomorphisms $G\to H$ with $H$ finite. Then you get a homomorphism $G\to H^2$ with some image $K$. Now $K$ has 2 non-conjugate homomorphisms to $H$, and it occurs as a finite quotient of $G$. So asking whether you have 2 such homomorphisms is the same as asking for such a finite quotient $K$.

Comment: @jacob: that's a nice observation, and I believe that it could be upgraded to a proof, but I would appreciate more details. I still don't see how you recover the isomorphism type. Is this a standard result in profinite group theory that you have a reference for? Or is the full argument short enough that you can give it in the text of the question?

Comment: How about the following proposed counterexample: $\mathbb{F}_2^\omega$ versus direct sum of $\omega_1$ copies of this? (Or one could even use countable support instead of finite support in the direct sum.) These both have size continuum, without any extra set-theoretic assumption.

Comment: (And is it true or not that etale fundamental groups are topologically finitely generated?)

Comment: @Joel: but is that direct sum still a profinite group?

Comment: I'm not sure...maybe not.

Comment: Joel: The countable direct sum will not be a profinite group, in general you need products to retain profinite-ness. 
Qiaochu: I see now that I should add some stuff in the question(such as the proof in the top.fin.gen case) and rephrase the questino slightly. Do you know what mathoverflow policiy is regarding this? Should I just do it with a disclaimer?

Comment: @jacob: in general the main kind of edits people don't like is edits that invalidate an existing answer, of which there isn't one. So that's probably fine. (Just kidding about the counterexample!)

Comment: @jacob: in the proof I don't see how we can conclude that $G$ surjects onto $H_n$ from only the assumption that $G$ and $H$ have the same finite quotients (by which I assumed you meant the same isomorphism classes, as finite groups, of finite quotients).

Comment: $H_n$ is a finite group onto which $H$ surjects, so it follows directly from the assumptions, no?

Comment: @jacob: got it. But $H_n$ is not itself a finite group of order at most $n$, is it? So the map $G \to H_n$ only factors through $G_m$ where $m = |H_n|$ a priori, right?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: $H_n$ has high order, true, but by definition it injects into a product of groups each of order at most $n$. That's how you get that the map factors through $G_n$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18691/discussion-between-jacob-and-qiaochu-yuan).

Comment: This hypothesis "have at most countably many finite Hausdorff quotients" for a profinite group, is the same as being metrizable, and is also equivalent to be either finite or homeomorphic to a Cantor set.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: The fact that a profinite group with only finitely many quotients of each finite index is determined by the list of isomorphism types of those quotients is indeed a standard fact in profinite group theory.  I've definitely seen it in John Wilson's book, and I'm pretty sure it's in Ribes-Zalesskii as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without the extra finiteness conditions, but also not relying on any set-theoretic assumptions, take $G = \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $H = G \times A$ for a nontrivial finite abelian group $A$. Both $G$ and $H$ have every possible finite abelian quotient, but only $H$ has torsion.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for this beautiful counterexample :)

Comment: I don't know the hat notation used in this context to define G.  Would someone add a few words in an explanatory comment or edit, please?  (Even if the words are "profinite completion", precisely what is being completed profinitely?)

Comment: @The Masked Avenger: $\mathbb{Z}$ is being completed profinitely. $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the profinite completion of the integers, otherwise known as the profinite integers. By the Chinese remainder theorem it may also be written as a product $\prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$ where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denotes the $p$-adic integers.

Comment: And you are then raising that to a countable direct power to build G.  (I think.)  Thanks for the additional clarity, and thanks for teaching me today.

Answer (score 1):

A more geometric example is as follows: let $k$ be a countable algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$, and pick a positive integer $n$. Let $G_n = \pi_1(\mathbb{A}^n_k)$, the etale fundamental group of the $n$-dimensional affine space over $k$. By Raynaud's solution of the Abhyankar conjecture, $G_1$ admits as finite quotients (precisely) all finite groups with no prime-to-$p$ quotient. Therefore, the same holds for all $G_n$. However, the cohomological dimension of $G_n$ equals $n$, and hence $G_n\not\cong G_m$ for $n\neq m$.

Comment: I find this use of the word 'geometric' amusing.

Comment: The use of "geometric" for algebraic features interpretable in algebraic geometry is very common.

Comment: @YCor -- I know. It's especially amusing in characteristic $p$.